# how to test specific line in the txt file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text

I create txt file that contain three lines

```
hi123
ok
good
```

and I want to test if the my var is equal to some line in the txt file
the first line in my txt file is equal to my var when i print it but the test is give me False like this

```
file = open("copy.txt", "r")
all_lines_variable = file.readlines()
var = 'hi123'
print(all_lines_variable[0], all_lines_variable[0] == var)
file.close()
```

and the output is

```
hi123
 False
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the specific line in your file is not `'hi123'`, in fact, it's `'hi123\n'`. There is a newline at the end. So you can change your `var` to `'hi123\n'` or try to remove any newline character.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a line break at the end of the line. You can see that by the fact that `print` wrote the contents of `var` in a new line.

If the `var` contents just have to be in that line, you could use `print(all_lines_variable[0], var in all_lines_variable[0])` instead.

Otherwise, you could remove the last character of the line (the break) and use it in the comparison like this:
`print(all_lines_variable[0], all_lines_variable[0][:-1] == var)`